# How to constrain the element type of an iterator?

Tags: rust

I’m converting some older Rust code to work on 1.0.0. I need to convert a function that takes an iterator over characters, which used to be written like this:

```
 fn f<I: Iterator<char>>(char_iter: I)
```

Now that `Iterator` doesn’t take a parameter, the constraint on `I` can only be `I: Iterator`. The element type is then `I::Item`. Is there a way to express the constraint that `I::Item` = `char`? (Or should I be doing this another way entirely?)

Answer (score 6):

```
fn f<I: Iterator<Item = char>>(char_iter: I)
```

Associated types were recently added to the language, and many library types were updated to take advantage of them. For example, [`Iterator`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) defines one associated type, named `Item`. You can add a constraint on the associated type by writing the name of the associated type, an equals sign, and the type you need.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I was able to figure this out from reading some RFC discussions, and the answer is that you can instantiate associated types in the trait (like signature fibration in ML):

```
fn f<I: Iterator<Item = char>>(char_iter: I)
```

Soon it should be possible to use equality constraints in `where` clauses, but this doesn’t work in 1.0.0-alpha:

```
fn f<I: Iterator>(char_iter: I) where I::Item == char
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write `I: Iterator<Item = char>`. At some point in the future, a `where` clause like `where I::Item == char` may work too, but not now.