# How can I enforce equality of two associated type parameters of traits?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I have a function `f` which takes two arguments of the same type, and a function `g` which takes two arguments of different types, but both types have to store the same value, so that `g` can call `f` with the values contained in the arguments to `f`. I currently implemented something like this:

```
fn f<T>(a: T, b: T) {}

trait A {
    type A;
    fn getter(&self) -> Self::A;
}

fn g<T: A, U: A>(a: T, b: U) {
    f(a.getter(), b.getter())
}
```

What do I have to add to the definition of `g` to make it work?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29345708/155423; http://stackoverflow.com/q/27893501/155423.

Answer (score 4):

A `where` clause works fine:

```
fn g<T, U>(a: T, b: U)
where
    T: A,
    U: A<A = T::A>, // where T::A is equal to B::A
{
    f(a.getter(), b.getter())
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. It's not done by a `where` clause, but this way:

```
fn g<T: A, U: A<A = T::A>>(a: T, b: U) { // where T::A is equal to B::A
    f(a.getter(), b.getter())
}
```